# Lightbox - Trigger gallery

Tags: lightbox

I have a light box gallery and I have it so it displays all the images and the user is able to click on any of them to trigger the gallery. Now when the window is too small, I have an icon inplace of the gallery. When the user clicks on it, I want to trigger the galley, currently when I click on the icon, the 1st image of the gallery appears, but it appears twice. So how do I trigger the gallery without the first image appearing twice. Here is my code: The first item is the icon.

```
<div class="design-centre-gallery">
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><i class="fa fa-picture-o design-centre-gallery-btn"></i></a>
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/1.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/2.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/2.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/3.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/3.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/4.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/4.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/5.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/5.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/6.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/6.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/7.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/7.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/8.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/8.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/9.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/9.jpg" /></a> 
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/10.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/10.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/11.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/11.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/12.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/12.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/13.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/13.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/14.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/14.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/15.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/15.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/16.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/16.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/17.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/17.jpg" /></a>   
                    <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/18.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/18.jpg" /></a>   
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing the icon:

```
<a href="images/design-centre-gallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><i class="fa fa-picture-o design-centre-gallery-btn"></i></a>
```

and change the look of the `first-child` using CSS Media Queries:

```
.design-centre-gallery a:first-child {
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.design-centre-gallery a:first-child:before {
    content:"\f03e";
    font-size:58px;
    color:#FFF;
}

.design-centre-gallery a:first-child img {
        display: none;
        float:right;
        padding:10px;
}

.design-centre-gallery a img{
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){

    .design-centre-gallery a:first-child:before {
        content:"";
        font-size:58px;
        color:#FFF;
    }


    .design-centre-gallery a:first-child {
        display:initial;
        text-align:right;
        padding:0px;
        font-family:initial;
    }

    .design-centre-gallery a img {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .design-centre-gallery a:first-child img {
        float: none;
        padding:0px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a link to the image in your gallery twice, the first one is with the icon, which you want. You need to remove the duplicate after that with the same href.

Remove this  link:

```
  <a href="images/design-centre-gallery/1.jpg" data-lightbox="design-centre-gallery"><img src="images/design-centre-gallery/1.jpg" /></a>
```